# Add the ability to show comments without adding a comment using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

This case mildly annoys me:

I have a Q&A open. I see there are hidden comments under a post and want to expand them using the keyboard shortcuts. That is achievable by pressing <kbd>C</kbd>.

Here is how the help information (pressing <kbd>?</kbd>) describes this action:

> <kbd>C</kbd> add/show comments

The problem is that this expands the comments *and* opens up the form to add a comment. Thus the focus shifts to the text box, so I cannot use any further keyboard shortcuts - instead, I just type them as a comment. My current workaround is to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch the focus over away from the text box and this be able to keep interacting with the page via shortcuts.

This is a divergence in behaviour when using a mouse and the keyboard shortcuts, which makes the latter more irritating.

I would like the ability to *only* show the comments without automatically trying to add another one like we can currently do when not using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Yeah, a long while ago, the button to add and show comments were the same: it would say "add/show [x] more comment(s)" instead of separate "add a comment" and "show [x] more comment(s)". I think the key shortcut was implemented at that time.